# error while trying to disable cache

Tags: magento-1.9, error, cache, backend, ce-1.9.1.2

I have just updated to magento 1.9.1.2 from 1.9.0.1.

(In the new magento, I use the database i was using in previous version)

when i try to disable the magento cache in backend, i have an error.

here is the log :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1077:"Error in file: "/***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'core_email_queue' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `core_email_queue` (
  `message_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Message Id' ,
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NULL COMMENT 'Entity Type' ,
  `event_type` varchar(128) NULL COMMENT 'Event Type' ,
  `message_body_hash` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Message Body Hash' ,
  `message_body` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Message Body' ,
  `message_parameters` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Message Parameters' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time' ,
  `processed_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Finish Time' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`),
  INDEX `0ADECE62FD629241C147389ADF20706E` (`entity_id`, `entity_type`, `event_type`, `message_body_hash`)
) COMMENT='Email Queue' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";i:1;s:1202:"#0 /***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.4', '1.6.0.6')
#2 /***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.4', '1.6.0.6')
#3 /***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /***/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /***/index.php(96): Mage::run('fr_store', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:66:"/index.php/admin/cache/index/key/91230960375950b4c11a2b6fd88965f9/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason your `core_resource` table is not up to date. Magento thinks that the `Mage_Core` module needs an upgrade.
I don't know why this happens, but as long as the table already exists you can just tell Magento that your module is up to date.
Backup the data from the `core_resource` table, in case I'm wrong.
then run this query on your db

```
UPDATE 
    `core_resource` 
SET 
    `version` = '1.6.0.6', 
    `data_version` = '1.6.0.6' 
WHERE 
    `code` = `core_setup`.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no 'Mage_Core' in 'core_resource'...

Comment: It should have been core_setup. Sorry for that. Just a bad habbit I picked up from magento 2

Comment: No Pb, It is already kind you help me..But, It is already in 1.6.0.6...

Comment: I have checked in my database using phpmyadmin and all the column added by upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php are already present as well as the index... How to stop this script to be called? How to check that my database is uptodate ?